# Tracking revisions in Excel in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, ms-word

I have managed to keep Microsoft Word's track revisions property on. It is working fine.

How do I do the same for MS Excel 2007 and above? Follwing is my code for word (which is working fine) and next is for Excel that I am trying to execute.

1. Word:

   ```
   Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
   Word.Document tempDoc = app.Documents.Open(path);
   tempDoc.TrackRevisions = true;
   tempDoc.Protect(typ, ref missing, ref password, ref missing, ref missing);
   ```
2. Excel:

   ```
   Excel.Application ex_APP = new Excel.Application();
   Workbook wrk = ex_APP.Workbooks.Open(path);
   ```

not able to go past this. When I try doing

```
wrk.
```

I don't get property as trackReviosons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I am currently doing it it seems to work really well

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

Then you get active workbook

```
//Gets Excel and gets Activeworkbook and worksheet
Excel.Application oXL;
Excel.Workbook oWB;
Excel.Worksheet oSheet;
oXL = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"); 
oXL.Visible = true;
oWB = (Excel.Workbook)oXL.ActiveWorkbook; 

docProps = oWB.CustomDocumentProperties
```

Comment: Check out this link as well. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-HP010197381.aspx

Comment: I am not able to get the first lines ActiveWorkbook? dont know why

Comment: what do you mean not able to get the first line, you are trying to access the active workbook right?

Comment: YEs. When I type the code " this.Application." i dont get activeworkbook

Comment: thanks, can you tell me how to onvert a byte[] in pdf.? I am trying to do it, but it is saying that file is corroupted

Comment: okay, open a new question and send me the link to the new question here and I will show you how to do it

Comment: please see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252348/how-to-open-a-file-stored-in-database-in-pdf